# the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed

Tags: windows-server-2008

i got this message when i try to login the file server "the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed "

can anyone help me

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Probably the workstation account password has come out of sync or has become corrupted.

Basically you have re authenticate with the domain, in other words, rejoining the domain.

I refer you to [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162797) with more details on how to verify if this is the problem, and how to solve it.

Comment: What KB?

Comment: So sorry, I messed up the link. You probably googled it up already, but here it is: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216393 - also relevant: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150493

Comment: NEW version of link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162797

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for this error may be the system time difference on both machines. If they differ too much (think 2 hours or more) authentication fails

Comment: If time differs more than 5 minutes, kerberos breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This KB also applies. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162797

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i know my response is late 
but sometimes if you have two domain controllers and the bdc does not sync with the pdc this happens.temp solution is to stop AD services on the BDC 
long term solution fix the syncing issue.

Answer (score -1):

on your workstation, unjoin from domain - restart, add it to workgroup then restart
on the server - in active directory users and computers, delete the computer account

then on the workstation, re-join to the domain.

Comment: You only need to unjoin (it'll force you to join a workgroup at the same time), reboot, reset the computer account on the domain, then rejoin the domain. No deleting necessary, no restarting the server!

Comment: A trick I've noticed (works for me at least) is to rejoin the domain by stipping the tld. So for a "contoso.com" joined computer, you can't join "contoso.com", but you can join... "contoso"! Which is really the same domain, of course, but the GUI won't stop you from joining because it thinks it is a different one. Saves you parting the domain if you like to use the GUI.